# Authentication with SMTP transport using Swiftmailer

Tags: authentication, yii, smtp, swiftmailer

I'm using Swiftmailer to send emails in my Yii based application and it works great, so there is no problems with the Swiftmailer extension wrapper. But now I want to use the SMPT transport to authenticate the users in my application against the mail server. The code I'm using:

```
$SM = Yii::app()->swiftMailer;

$mailHost = 'XXX'; 
$mailPort = XXX;

// New transport
$transport = $SM->smtpTransport($mailHost, $mailPort);

$transport->setUsername($username);
$transport->setPassword($password);
$transport->start();

if($transport->isStarted()){
    // authenticated;    
}else{
    // error;
}

$transport->stop();
```

This isn't working. When I set real login credentials instantly logs in. But when I type wrong ones, it spends some time but at last it logs in too. I don't know why this happens because just when using real credentials Swiftmailer can send emails.
I'm using the right API functions? I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php), when you call `start()`, started is always set to True.

I'm not familiar with switfmailer, but it looks like you'll want to check the results of authenticate()

Comment: Yes! Is authenticate() a method in the class transport? I haven't seen it. Let me check.